# ORDER before GROUPING in joined results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

- The user table
- The "experience" table which contains information about which school the current user goes to. This table can contain multiply schools (i.e. previous school history, or even jobs)

I wish to fetch the users table, and then also fetch the current school (by ordering by: exp_date)

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
u.user_id,
  u.firstname,
  pn.programme_name, 
  e.exp_start,
  en.firstname AS name 
FROM 
  edu_users u 
  LEFT JOIN edu_experience e ON e.exp_user = u.user_id 
  LEFT JOIN edu_users en ON en.user_id = e.exp 
  LEFT JOIN edu_programmes pn ON pn.programme_id = e.exp_position 
ORDER BY 
  exp_start DESC
```

And it returns this result:
[image]

The first result (from user id 1) is the one I need - the two below associated with user_id 1 should not be fetched.

How do I accomplish my this goal? I have tried with `group by user_id` but then the data is grouped before ordered, so the result looks like this:

[image]

Any ideas? I have tried with min() as described in this question: [ORDER BY date and time BEFORE GROUP BY name in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572110/order-by-date-and-time-before-group-by-name-in-mysql) but it doesn't work.

Comment: See the related question linked above. You'd want to use MAX(exp_start) instead of MIN, I'd think.

Comment: Thanks - I have already tried with MAX same results as MIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join against a subselect to get the latest experience for each user, and then join that back against experience (and onwards) to get the other details

Something like this

```
SELECT 
u.user_id,
  u.firstname,
  pn.programme_name, 
  e.exp_start,
  en.firstname AS name 
FROM 
  edu_users u 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT exp_user, MAX(exp_start) AS MaxExpStart FROM edu_experience GROUP BY exp_user) e1 ON e1.exp_user = u.user_id 
  LEFT JOIN edu_experience e ON e.exp_user = u.user_id AND e.exp_start = e1.MaxExpStart
  LEFT JOIN edu_users en ON en.user_id = e.exp 
  LEFT JOIN edu_programmes pn ON pn.programme_id = e.exp_position 
ORDER BY 
  exp_start DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL you need to use a related subquery, to only get the "latest" record for each user:

```
SELECT 
    u.user_id,
    u.firstname,
    pn.programme_name, 
    e.exp_start,
    en.firstname AS name 
FROM 
    edu_users u 
LEFT JOIN edu_experience e ON e.exp_user = u.user_id 
LEFT JOIN edu_users en ON en.user_id = e.exp 
LEFT JOIN edu_programmes pn ON pn.programme_id = e.exp_position 
WHERE e.exp_start = (
    SELECT MAX(exp_start) FROM edu_experience z
    WHERE z.exp_user = e.exp_user)
ORDER BY 
    exp_start DESC
```

Comment: Hi there - problem is it only fetches 1 result with above query.