# laravel eloquent sort by relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 models

- User
- Channel
- Reply

model relations

- `user` have `belongsToMany('App\Channel');`
- `channel` have `hasMany('App\Reply', 'channel_id', 'id')->oldest();`

let's say i have 2 channels

- channel-1
- channel-2

`channel-2` has latest replies than `channel-1`

now, i want to order the user's channel by its channel's current reply.
just like some chat application.
how can i order the user's channel just like this?

- channel-2
- channel-1

i already tried some codes. but nothing happen

```
// User Model
public function channels()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Channel', 'channel_user')
                    ->withPivot('is_approved')
                    ->with(['replies'])
                    ->orderBy('replies.created_at'); // error
    
    }
// also
public function channels()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Channel', 'channel_user')
                    ->withPivot('is_approved')
                    ->with(['replies' => function($qry) {
                        $qry->latest();
                    }]);
    }
// but i did not get the expected result
```

**EDIT**
also, i tried this. yes i did get the expected result but it would not load all channel if there's no reply.

```
public function channels()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Channel')
                ->withPivot('is_approved')
                ->join('replies', 'replies.channel_id', '=', 'channels.id')
                ->groupBy('replies.channel_id')
                ->orderBy('replies.created_at', 'ASC');
}
```

Comment: for this case, prefer "join" rather than "with"

Comment: hmm, so i can't do this with eloquent?..

Comment: @kapil.dev Hi, i tried join method. and it works as i expected. but it will just return all channels that has replies.

Comment: use left join, syntax : join('table_name','table_name.col1','=','table2.fkcol','left')

Comment: this package can help you https://github.com/fico7489/laravel-eloquent-join

Answer (score 18):

According to my knowledge, **eager load** `with` method run 2nd query. That's why you can't achieve what you want with **eager loading** `with` method.

I think use `join` method in combination with **relationship method** is the solution. The following solution is fully tested and work well.

```
// In User Model
public function channels()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Channel', 'channel_user')
        ->withPivot('is_approved');
}

public function sortedChannels($orderBy)
{
    return $this->channels()
            ->join('replies', 'replies.channel_id', '=', 'channel.id')
            ->orderBy('replies.created_at', $orderBy)
            ->get();
}
```

Then you can call `$user->sortedChannels('desc')` to get the list of **channels** order by replies `created_at` attribute.

For condition like **channels** (which may or may not have replies), just use `leftJoin` method.

```
public function sortedChannels($orderBy)
    {
        return $this->channels()
                ->leftJoin('replies', 'channel.id', '=', 'replies.channel_id')
                ->orderBy('replies.created_at', $orderBy)
                ->get();
    }
```

**Edit:**

If you want to add `groupBy` method to the query, you have to pay special attention to your `orderBy` clause. Because in **Sql** nature, `Group By` clause run first before `Order By` clause. See detail this problem at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572110/order-by-date-and-time-before-group-by-name-in-mysql).

So if you add `groupBy` method, you have to use `orderByRaw` method and should be implemented like the following.

```
return $this->channels()
                ->leftJoin('replies', 'channels.id', '=', 'replies.channel_id')
                ->groupBy(['channels.id'])
                ->orderByRaw('max(replies.created_at) desc')
                ->get();
```

Comment: why use join when we are already using eloquent relation, I'll suggest just use join and apply orderby

Comment: Because the joined table's fields will be on the same row so ordering is possible.

Comment: so i used join method like this.
`return $this->belongsToMany('App\Channel', 'channel_user')
                    ->withPivot('is_approved')
                    ->join('replies', 'replies.channel_id', '=', 'channels.id')
                    ->orderBy('replies.created_at', 'DESC');`
but when specific channel has no reply. it would cause an error.

Comment: @Hitori. I will comment under my own post cause I don't want to annoy other peoples' one. I've carefully analyze your problem. As first, your original question asked about to query the channels. But now you describe your problem about to query the replies. Please exactly describe the problem. Is it "to query channels" or "to query replies of each channels".

Comment: @Steve.NayLinAung, i'm so sorry for the mislead. hmm. think of it like the facebook messages. i want to display all channels by its replies.created_at

Comment: @Hitori. See my updated answer and accept correct if it give you the solution.

Comment: The solution at the bottom works. But if you use the top proposed solution then `sortedChannels` will give you duplicate channels for each reply (because of the join). So that didnt work for me, but the latter is good.

Answer (score 4):

Inside your channel class you need to create this `hasOne` relation (you channel `hasMany` **replies**, but it `hasOne` **latest reply**):

```
public function latestReply()
{
    return $this->hasOne(\App\Reply)->latest();
}
```

You can now get all channels ordered by latest reply like this:

```
Channel::with('latestReply')->get()->sortByDesc('latestReply.created_at');
```

To get all channels from the user ordered by latest reply you would need that method:

```
public function getChannelsOrderdByLatestReply()
{
    return $this->channels()->with('latestReply')->get()->sortByDesc('latestReply.created_at');
}
```

where `channels()` is given by:

```
public function channels()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Channel');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you don't have to specify the name of the pivot table if you follow [Laravel's naming convention](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) so your code looks a bit cleaner:

```
public function channels()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Channel') ...
```

Secondly, you'd have to call `join` explicitly to achieve the result in one query:

```
public function channels()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Channel::class) // a bit more clean
        ->withPivot('is_approved')
        ->leftJoin('replies', 'replies.channel_id', '=', 'channels.id') // channels.id
        ->groupBy('replies.channel_id')
        ->orderBy('replies.created_at', 'desc');
}
```

Comment: thanks, my code already looks like this. but it would not get all channels that has no replies yet

Comment: @Hitori just use `leftJoin` then

Comment: @Hitori yes, `leftJoin` should do the trick. It would get all the channels even if there's no replies (take a look at my edit)

Comment: Thanks ! it works now. i also grouped replies by channel_id.

Comment: Hi, @Quinn Daley. i noticed that the query i made seems like it takes only the first reply on the channel not on the latest one.

Comment: @Hitori I don't quite understand what you mean. «Takes only the first reply on the channel not on the latest one»?

Comment: @Hitori. May be you should use 'desc' instead of 'asc' when ordering created_at timestamp.

Comment: wait i'll post the result

Comment: @QuinnDaley and steve. take a look at EDIT.

Comment: @Hitori the reason lies somewhere else. Check how you sort data on the frontend. The query should return replies in the descending order

Comment: @Hitori, In my opinion, the query is correct and do its job. But this query is executed per user. That's why you also need to consider how you fetch your users from database. Ordering of user can also affect this list. Or may be due to some frontend ordering logic as Quinn said.

Comment: i think it's not. i recently commented on public chat. now it should on the top list. but when i dumped the results of query. the public chat was still on the bottom of the result

Comment: @Hitori i think i got it. It is because you group the query  with channel id.

Comment: @Steve.NayLinAung Hi, i grouped the query with channel id was because it would give the replies of each channels not the channels.. 
of course it will give the correct order of the replies.

Comment: also, i tried to group by it replies.channel_id. same results. in the meantime, i used javascript Array.sorting to achieve what i want on the frontend

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `hasOne()` relationship, you can sort all the records by doing:

```
$results = Channel::with('reply')
                   ->join('replies', 'channels.replay_id', '=', 'replies.id')
                   ->orderBy('replies.created_at', 'desc')
                   ->paginate(10);
```

This sorts all the `channels` records by the newest replies (assuming you have only one reply per channel.) This is not your case, but someone may be looking for something like this (as I was.)