# Laravel eloquent sort query

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to **sort** the users from my users table **by** the combined value of their distance in the activities table. The following code returns something like this.

[image]

I'm trying to figure out **how to sort** this data by the sum_distance value.
Also I can't seem to figure out **how to display** just the sum_distance data as $item->sum_distance doesn't return anything. (because it's nested inside somewhere I guess)

User model

```
protected $fillable = ['strava_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'sex', 'avatar', 'email', 'token'];

public function sumDistance()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Activity')
        ->selectRaw('user_id, sum(distance) as sum_distance')
        ->groupBy('user_id')
        ->orderBy('sum_distance', 'desc');
}
```

Activity model

```
protected $fillable = ['activityId', 'user_id', 'name', 'distance', 'moving_time', 'start_date'];
```

Controller

```
public function index(Strava $strava)
{

    $list = User::with('sumDistance')->get();

    return view('leaderboard', compact('list'));

}
```

View

```
<ul>
    @foreach($list as $item)
        <li>{{ $item }}</li><br>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: Try `return view('leaderboard')->with('list',$list));`

Comment: [laravel eloquent sort by relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40837690/laravel-eloquent-sort-by-relationship)

Answer (score 0):

You can't order the user results by a related model as part of the SQL query because eloquent gets the relationships in a separate query. You could of course do a join but that will defeat the purpose of using the ORM. Here's what you can do:

```
public function sumDistance()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Activity')
        ->selectRaw('user_id, sum(distance) as sum_distance')
        ->groupBy('user_id');
}
```

Then sort after you've gotten the result:

```
public function index(Strava $strava)
{

    $list = User::with('sumDistance')->get()->sort(function ($a,$b) {
           return $a->sumDistance->sum_distance <=> $b->sumDistance->sum_distance; 
    });

    return view('leaderboard', compact('list'));

}
```

Comment: I see where you're coming from. yet the ->sortBy("sumDistance.sum_distance") doesn't seem to change the order of the results at all.

Comment: @RobbeR try the update if you're using PHP 7+ (if not then use a subtraction instead of `<=>`)

Answer (score 0):

If your eloquent query returns collection then you can use `sortByDesc()` method

```
public function index(Strava $strava)
{

    $list = User::with('sumDistance')->get();

    $list = $list->sortByDesc('sum_distance');

    return view('leaderboard', compact('list'));

}
```