# Sort by related table's fileds using Eloquent not joining

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I used Eloquent method to work with tables. I did not use query and joins . Just making relations with hasMany and belongsTo. And I dont want to use joins and queries. 
I should sort the results based on some fields. Sorting for main table fields work without any problem. But when I want to sort by related table fields, I get error.

> Request URL:
>   http://localhost:8000/admin/pagination/fetch_data?page=1&sortby=product.product_title&sorttype=asc
>
> Request Method: GET Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error

This is my code.

**Comment**

```php
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this-> belongsTo('App\User', "comment_userid");
    }

    public function confirmerUser()
    {
        return $this-> belongsTo('App\User', "comment_confirmeruserid");
    }

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Product", "comment_productid");
    }
}
```

**Product**

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', "comment_productid");
    }
}
```

**User**

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', "comment_userid");
    }

    public function comments_confirmer()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', "comment_confirmeruserid");
    }
}
```

**In controller**

```php
public function controller_fetch_data(Request $request)
{
    if( $request->ajax() ) {
        $sort_by = $request->get('sortby');
        $sort_type = $request->get('sorttype');
        $comments = Comment::with('user', 'confirmerUser', 'product')
            ->orderBy($sort_by, $sort_type)->paginate(5);
        $p_pagenumber = $request['page'];
        return view("adminPanel.comment_list")
            ->with('p_pagenumber', $p_pagenumber)
            ->with('comments', $comments)
            ->render();
    }
}
```

**In view**

```js
function fetch_data(page, sort_type, sort_by)
{
    $.ajax({
        url : "/admin/pagination/fetch_data?page=" + page + "&sortby=" + sort_by + "&sorttype=" + sort_type,
        success : function(data) {
            $("#table_data").html('');
            $("#table_data").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the error?

Comment: Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/pagination/fetch_data?page=1&sortby=product.product_title&sorttype=asc
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: 500 is very abstract. check your logs in `storage/logs` and give us detailed info

Comment: I am not sure you can avoid `join`. Looks related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40837690/laravel-eloquent-sort-by-relationship

Comment: I am not sure. But I think that when I use hasMeny And belongsTo, There is not need to return to join and query. And Eloquent has to support all these type of requests. But If you think, ordering does not support by Eloquent, Please say me. @ Oluwatobi Samuel Omisakin

Comment: Can this technology alone be able to handle all sorting situations or does it have to go back to Join, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Laravel Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections) for eloquent relationships.

```
$comments = Comment::with('user', 'confirmerUser', 'product')->get();
$comments = collect($comments)->sortBy($sort_by)->splice(5);
```

Use **[sortBy()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-sortby)** or **[sortByDesc()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-sortbydesc)** for *order* and **[splice()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-splice)** for *pagination*

Hope this helps. Cheers!