# Sort the results returned by model relation laravel

Tags: laravel

I have 2 table:

```
products: id, name
auctions: id, product_id, expired_time
```

Model product

```
function getAuctions(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Auction', 'product_id', 'id');
}
```

How can I do the same as below(auctions.expired_time not working):

```
Controller
function getProductAuctions(){
    return \App\Models\Product::with('getAuctions')->whereHas('getAuctions', function(){})->orderBy('auctions.expired_time', 'asc');
}
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laravel eloquent sort by relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40837690/laravel-eloquent-sort-by-relationship)

Comment: Shouldn't your `getAuctions()` relationship be called `getAuction()`, since it can only return one auction, or even better following Laravel best practices it should be called `auction()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `sortBy()` method. That method applies to collections only.

```
function getProductAuctions(){
    $products = \App\Models\Product::all();
    return $products->sortBy(function ($product, $key) {
         return  $product->getAuctions->expired_time;
    })
}
```

This should now sort your products collection by the auctions expired time, if you want reversed order, you can just use `sortByDesc()` method, rest is the same. Also, in your product model, if you are having `hasOne()` relationship, rename the function name to `getAuction()` or even better `auction()` (singular).

Comment: Pretty inefficient to sort the collection (looping every record) instead of doing it with a query, and this disables a bunch of eloquent features like paging etc.

Comment: @AnNguyễn, if it solved your problem, please upvote and approve the answer so others can know. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use one of these to get sort your result
**in your controller**

```
function getProductAuctions(){
    return \App\Models\Product::with('getAuctions')->whereHas('getAuctions', function($query){
$query->orderBy('expired_time', 'asc');
})->get();
}
```

and if you want to sort in your model then just use this

```
function getAuctions(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Auction', 'product_id', 'id')->orderBy('expired_time', 'asc');
}
```

and thats all no need to do any thing...your result is already sorted

Comment: The result was not what I wanted it to be, it just sort the relational table

Answer (score 0):

Thank everyone. I found the answer here and I find it correct: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/order-by-on-relationship
"When you use the with method the Eloquent makes another query in database to retrieve the related data using whereIn. This is why we can't order by a relation field."