# How to filter the result Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web

Hard to describe what i want, but I will try:
First of all, i have 2 tables: employee and salary. I joined 2 tables by this SQL command:

```
"SELECT employee.id, employee.employee_name, employee.image, salary.year, salary.month, salary.day, salary.total_salary, salary.id, salary.created
                        FROM employee
                 JOIN salary ON salary.employee_id=employee.id"
```

to get all value i inserted, after execute, i got:

```
Created              name    year     month   day(working)       total_salary
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-12-17 20:41      A      2016       1         31              1550000
2016-12-17 21:49      A      2016       1         20              2000000
2016-12-17 22:49      A      2016       2         20              2000000
2016-12-18 22:43      B      2016       2         15              1550000
2016-12-18 23:43      B      2016       2         10              1000000
2016-12-18 23:49      B      2016       2         1                100000
```

After that, i want to get the newest value per month, so i add this command to the end of sql above:

```
 GROUP BY employee.employee_name, salary.year, salary.month"
```

and got this:

```
Created              name    year     month   day(working)       total_salary
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-12-17 20:41      A      2016       1         31              1550000
2016-12-17 22:49      A      2016       2         20              2000000
2016-12-18 22:43      B      2016       2         15              1550000
```

What query will return the following result?

```
Created              name    year     month   day(working)       total_salary
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-12-17 21:49      A      2016       1         20              2000000
2016-12-17 22:49      A      2016       2         20              2000000
2016-12-18 23:49      B      2016       2         1                100000
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, you want to group them by `month` and yet in your desired output there are 2 of the same `month` that seems contradictory.

Comment: you can see each of Employee have many Month, i i just want to display each month of a employee. Seems a little bit complex :))

Comment: If you put actual tables it would be more helpful to test query.  For the absence of that I can say that you just write subquery for calculating total for each employee and then join it to main table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My starting point was after your joins, I just made a table that has the data as your first result.

With this query:

```
SELECT created, name, year, month, day, total_salary FROM 
( SELECT * FROM employees
  ORDER BY created DESC
) AS sub
GROUP BY name, month, year;
```

I've got the results you asked for:

```
Created              name    year     month   day(working)       total_salary
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-12-17 21:49      A      2016       1         20              2000000
2016-12-17 22:49      A      2016       2         20              2000000
2016-12-18 23:49      B      2016       2         1                100000
```

Basically the trick was to handle the ordering before you pack them up into groups with **GROUP BY**
So I made a subQuery that just handles the ordering. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572110/order-by-date-and-time-before-group-by-name-in-mysql) helped me figure out how to do this.

Here's a [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/092e75/38) where you can play around and adjust it to your starting query.

Answer (score 1):

Before you group you should sort the entries by created date the newest entries are first:

```
ORDER BY salary.created DESC
```

Change the first query (you have to remove or alias one of the id's because you will have two columns with the same name):

```
SELECT employee.id as employee_id, employee.employee_name, employee.image, salary.year, salary.month, salary.day, salary.total_salary, salary.id, salary.created 
FROM employee JOIN salary ON salary.employee_id=employee.id 
ORDER BY salary.created DESC
```

So the last created are shown first. Then group the results like you did:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT employee.id as employee_id, employee.employee_name, employee.image, salary.year, salary.month, salary.day, salary.total_salary, salary.id, salary.created
    FROM employee
    JOIN salary ON salary.employee_id=employee.id 
    ORDER BY salary.created DESC 
) as employee_salary 
GROUP BY employee_salary.employee_name, employee_salary.year, employee_salary.month
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help but it still don't work for me :( , the result still return the same as i described above

Comment: Can you send me a dump of those 2 tables? Or just some example data i can play with? I created 2 tables and with my query i got the result i think you wanted...