# Android Greendao - group and order by

Tags: android, sqlite, orm, greendao

I'm using **GreenDAO** in my project.

I have a chats table which contains all the messages.
I want to group by the `chat_id` and order the messages in descending order by the timestamp of the message.

so what I'm trying to get is a list that contains the most recent message of each chat the user has.

this is the code I'm using:

```
Chats.queryBuilder()
     .orderDesc(ChatsDAO.Properties.TimeStamp)
     .where(ChatsDAO.Properties.UserId.eq(user_id))
     .where(new WhereCondition.StringCondition("1 GROUP BY chat_id"))
     .list();
```

but still, the code above gives me a list which contains the first message of each chat, instead of the recent message.

is there any way to make a raw query using greenDAO and select what I want?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a raw query using GreenDAO as follow. Also, check the [link](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/queries/#Raw_queries)

```
 Query<User> query = userDao.queryBuilder().where(
 new StringCondition("_ID IN " +
 "(SELECT USER_ID FROM USER_MESSAGE WHERE READ_FLAG = 0)")
 ).build();
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. tried. didn't help. it keeps crashing. i'm trying to do something like in this link using greendao 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572110/order-by-date-and-time-before-group-by-name-in-mysql

Comment: `.where(new WhereCondition.StringCondition("1 GROUP BY chat_id"))`

Why you are using this in your query ?

Comment: `.where(new WhereCondition.StringCondition("1 GROUP BY chat_id"))`

try your query without using this ....

Comment: I want to group all the messages by their chat_id. 
I saw that was the syntax for grouping in greendao.
but doesn't matter- I used raw query for what I needed - seem to be working