# MariaDB group by date order by date desc not working

Tags: mariadb, groupwise-maximum

I have a table like this:

```
date
2020-03-11 10:41:26
2020-03-11 17:51:15
2020-03-12 10:45:28
2020-03-12 17:41:28
```

I want the result:

```
datech        date                cnt
2020年3月12日  2020-03-12 17:41:28 2
2020年3月11日  2020-03-11 17:51:15 2
```

I have tried

```
Select *, count(*) as cnt from (
  Select (DATE_FORMAT((date),'%Y年%c月%d日')) as datech, date
  from tablea where 1=1
  order by date desc
) as t         
GROUP BY datech order by date desc
```

but the result date is asc

```
datech         date                cnt
2020年3月12日  2020-03-12 10:45:28 2
2020年3月11日  2020-03-11 10:41:26 2
```

How can I desc date?
Thanks.

Comment: add limit in subquery works https://stackoverflow.com/a/35202755/7955124

Comment: Which "time" do you want in each grouping?

Comment: the latest time in group 17:41:28 17:51:15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select datech, max(date) as date, count(*) as cnt from (
  Select (DATE_FORMAT((date),'%Y年%c月%d日')) as datech, date
  from tablea where 1=1
) as t         
GROUP BY datech order by date desc;
```