# Laravel Eloquent get first row from a group by

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following table in MySQL with an auto-increment ID field and an auto timestamp field(not mentioned here).
I am trying to group by the rows on order# and get the latest row.

Order Table -

| id | order# | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | pending |
| 2 | 100 | processing |
| 3 | 100 | delivered |
| 4 | 101 | pending |
| 5 | 101 | processing |
| 6 | 101 | cancelled |

Expected Answer -

| id | order# | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 100 | delivered |
| 6 | 101 | cancelled |

So far this is all I could come up with. I spend few hours trying to google a solution, but couldnt find something clear.

`SELECT * FROM TABLE  ORDER BY order# , id DESC;`

Comment: instead of ordering by the id, how about using the timestamps? Don't you have an updated_at column?

Comment: I do have an updated_at, but I need the latest row for every order#. I was trying id, because its autoincremented and would always be higher than the previous entries. (not sure if its safe)

Comment: It should be if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: that doesnt give me the first row though, it will give me all the rows ordered in that manner by updated_at

Comment: This has already been answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572110/order-by-date-and-time-before-group-by-name-in-mysql/6572292 . Just use it as a subquery. `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ...) A GROUP BY id`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ORDER BY date and time BEFORE GROUP BY name in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572110/order-by-date-and-time-before-group-by-name-in-mysql)