# Group by last occurrence

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, mysql-5.7

i am trying to get the last rows where rec_p_id = 4 SORTED by the timestamp. Since i do not want to have all the results WHERE rec_p_id = 4, i am using GROUP BY to group it by send_p_id.

My SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT * 
        FROM chat 
      WHERE rec_p_id= "4" 
      ORDER 
        BY timestamp DESC) as sub 
 GROUP 
    BY send_p_id
```

My table looks like this:

**Table chat**

| c_id | send_p_id | rec_p_id | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | 2020-05-01 14:46:00 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 2020-05-01 14:49:00 |
| 3 | 3 | 4 | 2020-05-01 14:50:00 |
| 4 | 7 | 4 | 2020-05-01 12:00:00 |
| 5 | 4 | 7 | 2020-05-01 12:10:00 |
| 6 | 7 | 4 | 2020-05-01 12:20:00 |
| 7 | 9 | 4 | 2020-05-01 16:50:00 |
| 8 | 9 | 4 | 2020-05-01 17:00:00 |

I want to get the last occurrences:

| c_id | send_p_id | rec_p_id | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 | 4 | 2020-05-01 14:50:00 |
| 6 | 7 | 4 | 2020-05-01 12:20:00 |
| 8 | 9 | 4 | 2020-05-01 17:00:00 |

But instead i get all the first ones:

| c_id | send_p_id | rec_p_id | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | 2020-05-01 14:46:00 |
| 4 | 7 | 4 | 2020-05-01 12:00:00 |
| 7 | 9 | 4 | 2020-05-01 16:50:00 |

I saw the query i am using in this question: [ORDER BY date and time BEFORE GROUP BY name in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572110/order-by-date-and-time-before-group-by-name-in-mysql/6572292)

it seems to work for all of them. What am i doing wrong with my query?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whatever you think this query does, I'm afraid you're mistaken. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @aajuu19 did you have chance to try my asnwer?

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for your comment. I will keep that in mind the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking to your expected  result seems you are looking for

```
select max(c_id) c_id, send_p_id, min(timestamp) timestamp
from chat WHERE rec_p_id= "4" 
group by send_p_id
ORDER BY c_id
```

Group by is for aggregated result  ..
an use without aggregation function can produce unpredicatble result and in version > 5.6 can produce error

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me. I guess i still have a lot to learn in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17338495/3407539) answer and built [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/299839/7) setup for you.
The code below is the copy of it, so that you can run it later yourself.
For the solution the example from the [official manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html).

```sql
CREATE TABLE chat
(
        c_id INT PRIMARY KEY
    ,   send_p_id INT
    ,   rec_p_id INT
    ,   timestamp DATETIME
     
);

INSERT INTO chat VALUES
    (1, 3,  4,  '2020-05-01 14:46:00')
,   (2, 3,  4,  '2020-05-01 14:49:00')
,   (3, 3,  4,  '2020-05-01 14:50:00')
,   (4, 7,  4,  '2020-05-01 12:00:00')
,   (5, 4,  7,  '2020-05-01 12:10:00')
,   (6, 7,  4,  '2020-05-01 12:20:00')
,   (7, 9,  4,  '2020-05-01 16:50:00')
,   (8, 9,  4,  '2020-05-01 17:00:00');
```

Solution:

```sql
SELECT c_id,
       send_p_id,
       rec_p_id,
       timestamp
FROM   chat AS c
WHERE  timestamp=(SELECT MAX(c1.timestamp)
              FROM chat AS c1
              WHERE c.send_p_id = c1.send_p_id)
AND send_p_id != 4
ORDER BY timestamp;
```

Comment: Hello Farukh and thanks for your answer. Your solution worked as well for me! Thanks to you and scais. Can i quick-check which of these queries is faster?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html) can help you.